# How can I show the desktop name when I'm switching virtual desktops in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Now that renaming windows desktops is possible in the latest Windows 10 build, it leaves me looking for an overlay of the name when I am switching desktops, or some other indication (custom wallpaper, taskbar text, etc.) that I am in that virtual desktop, since I almost never use Windows+Tab, but the buttons on my mouse. This feature was in Linux Mint and I loved it and found it very useful.

Is there a way to implement this? I'm assuming there is no inbuilt setting. How about a third party app I can use? If there is no such third party app, is there a script I could make (in C#, AHK, etc.), in which an event is triggered when the desktop is switched, and the event passes the desktop name to the script, and then I could display the name myself? Could be a great project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You beat me to it apparently. Also looking for such an answer.

Comment: My hard way is to use small wordpad title bars and put the desktop name there in a always-on window mode. The window is quite small to prevent it from being disturbing.  I have come across this AHK script (https://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip224.htm) but can't see where one can get desktop name. If one can get desktop then you could popup a small window with desktop names when switching.

Answer (score 5):

This did the job for me. [SylphyHornPlusWin11](https://github.com/hwtnb/SylphyHornPlusWin11)

> SylphyHornPlus is Virtual Desktop Tools for Windows 11 and 10.
> Provides global hotkeys, switching notification, change background and several functions to virtual desktop.

Go to the github page link. Go to releases. Download the zip. Unzip it, run the exe.
In the notification tray, right click icon>Settings>Notification>check 'display desktop name in notification window'.

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: The question is about Windows 10, not 11 and always installing some 3rd-party stuff from an unknown/untrusted source is not the solution.

Comment: Just shows Desktop 1 , Desktop 2 , ... :(

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi I'm using windows 10 and it shows the desktop names as how I named them. Maybe rename your desktops or restart the app or restart your pc?

Answer (score 2):

I find this very useful:

https://github.com/dankrusi/WindowsVirtualDesktopHelper and works on windows 10

[image]

Comment: Very useful solution! ! ! It makes my work incredibly clear!

Answer (score 1):

This app in the Windows Store released 2022. It's not free but has 7 day free trial. I just installed and it does exactly what's needed here: temporarily shows the virtual desktop name on the screen and also shows screen number in a small icon in the systray! Perfect!

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/virtual-desktop-indicator/9nhcl1xqwxf1

Answer (score 1):

Peach (https://peachapp.net/is) handles this nicely. Specifically, it

- Displays, in the center of the screen, the name of the desktop to which you're switching.
- Offers keyboard shortcuts for instantly switching across non-adjacent desktops. For example, Ctrl-Alt-9 (or Ctrl-Alt-F9, if you prefer) will take you instantly from (say) Desktop 2 to Desktop 9.
- Offers keyboard shortcuts for renaming desktops and for moving the current program from one desktop to another.

I don't know whether it's the best option, but it's the one that I'm using, and I wouldn't want to be without it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VirtualDesktopManager](https://github.com/m0ngr31/VirtualDesktopManager).

**Form the GitHub Page:**

> *This program was made for people who are using Windows 10's built-in Virtual Desktops, but who don't like the default key-binding, don't
> like how you can't cycle through your desktops (If you are on your
> last one you don't want to hotkey over to the first one 8 times), and
> don't like not knowing what desktop # they are on.*

There is no installation. Just download the .zip from the Releases, extract it and then run VirtualDesktopManager.exe.

You can use Task Scheduler to make it launch when you login so you don't have to launch it manually every reboot."

Comment: This doesn't work with Windows 11, unfortunately and hasn't been updated since 2016.